# Is there a convention to point to a set of example questions and answers related to some generic problem?

Tags: discussion

Usually you can see that comments or answers point to another question that might deal problem in question in more general or more abstract level.

But if you think about this example: a user asks a question, Q1, the problem is that there is a static variable that is accessed by many threads which might cause arbitrary behavior and there is a good answer to Q1 telling that.

Then there is another question Q2 "Why should I avoid static variables?". It might have tens of answers saying like "causing problems hard to trace" or having good examples of cases or so.

Then thinking about linking real examples - like Q1 - to Q2 that might illustrate the problem better so the OP or any other can easily browse the real cases / case studies.

- Should there be one answer having links to these cases?
- Should there
  be answer per link (not likely..)?
- Should there be a special tag created, in this case like [why-avoid-statics] to easily search problems related?
- Should users collect links in comments?

The above is only to illustrate the purpose of the question, not necessary taken as real alternatives.

A bit more clarification and as an example: if some question has other questions marked as duplicates of it - perhaps special cases of this Qs problem - is there some way to browse these duplicates as an examples of this generic problem?

Comment: Just close-vote a question that has been asked many times before.  You can pick *one* existing Q+A as the duplicate.  It is enough.  If the user needs more help then it is his job to edit his question to provide more details.

Comment: ok, but i meant just the opposite i'll edit my question. or is it so that there is also some information like "this Q has following duplicates: " somewhere?

Comment: If you go to the question that is marked as already having the answer, there will be a section titled "Linked" on the sidebar. Duplicates will show up there (along with some other questions). If there are a lot of linked questions, there will be a button underneath that says "see more linked questions..." The list won't be duplicates only, but all the duplicates will be in there.

Comment: ok, i searched one duplicate QD in meta, opened the Q that this QD is duplicate of. There is shown this QD in linked-section. User can browse all these through and it can be that 1/2 is something that really is a good example or has an answer that tells why it is so in this case. Also the duplicate case was just one example. I mean, should you find good examples and mark them as duplicates to this generic question-answer-problem ?